# Check if geographical point exists at location (x,y) in worldmap

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was assigned a text adventure game in class and one section of the code goes like this

```
class World:

   def __init__(self, mapdata, locdata, itemdata): 
       self.geographicalloc = {}

   def get_geographicalloc(self, x, y):
    '''Check if geographical location exists at location (x,y) in worldmap.
    Return Location object associated with this location if it does. Else, return None.
    Remember, locations represented by the number -1 on the map should return None.
    :param x: integer x representing x-coordinate of world map
    :param y: integer y representing y-coordinate of world map
    :return: Return Location object associated with this location if it does. Else, return None.
    '''
```

My code for this goes like this

```
for self.x and self.y not in self.geographicloc:
    return None    
return self.geographicalloc((x, y))
```

I am not really understanding the main concept of this question. For this part of the question it is a location on a text adventure game and i'm confused. I simply tried to remove all the code and just write

```
return self.geographicalloc((x, y))
```

but i get an error saying TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Does using `self.geographicalloc[(x, y)]` solve the problem? `dict` elements are retrieved using square brackets around the key, `[key]`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for more information.

Comment: @pascal no i get key error: (0, 0)

Comment: Yes, but note that this is a different error. Before, you had that your `dict` is not callable, since you tried to use it like a function, using parenthesis `()`. Now it tells you that you are using it correctly, but this specific key is not saved in your `dict`. To help you on this, the code you posted is not sufficient, as it doesn't show how the keys of `geographicalloc` are defined.